# Error after update Autofac.Mvc5 from 3.3.2 to 3.3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, custom-membershipprovider

I have a Error after update Autofac.Mvc5 from 3.3.2 to 3.3.3
I posted my issue to github https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/572#issuecomment-63236738 and got response that I need to ask here :)

Below my situation:

What I have:

```
// Setup DI as default MVC controller factory
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

I need this to use in injected property of Custom Membership Provider

```
protected IMembershipService MembershipService
{
    get
    {
         return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService();
    }
}
```

**issue: The dependency resolver is not of type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver'**

Please help me to solve this.

**UPDATE**
So now I have such error after update from 3.3.2 to

**The dependency resolver is not of type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver' and does not appear to be wrapped using DynamicProxy from the Castle Project. This issue could be the result of a change in the DynamicProxy implementation or the use of a different proxy library to wrap the dependency resolver.**

Any Ideas on how to solve that?

url to image error https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJJXX.png

**UPDATE**
Here what i found
github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/82cc138596e74095f50720319feb2a2ce734310d/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacDependencyResolver.cs
on this file we have part where exception throws for such text.
This is only one part in all source code, so I think I need to move forward and find out why I'm getting this issue. Also when and why my code request this method AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.
As I checked that I have NO direct calls of AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.
I need to investigate other variants (places) of calls.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: my issue: The dependency resolver is not of type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver'

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with your membership service - it's coming from the filter provider. Please update your question with: the list of packages/versions you're using (not just Autofac - everything); your app startup code (all of it); steps you've done to troubleshoot; and any other info that might help folks. Maybe a repro on GitHub? Unfortunately there is not enough here to help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Travis, I found out that if I comment builder.RegisterFilterProvider(); no more exceptions. Can you please explain do I need this method and why?

Comment: Just before resolving your service from DependencyResolver.Current, can you print out the actual type of the resolver?

e.g. `DependencyResolver.Current.GetType()`

Comment: I have updated the exception message to include the current type of the dependency resolver when it is not of type `AutofacDependencyResolver`.

https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/commit/15c607c74ea8ab7700ef43b6fddc1146c1ffba0a

Comment: this is what I see where before was request of builder.RegisterFilterProvider(); DependencyResolver.Current.GetType() {Name = "DefaultDependencyResolver" FullName = "System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver+DefaultDependencyResolver"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: The exception appears to be telling you the truth - that the current dependency resolver isn't Autofac, at least at the time the current resolver is being accessed. We really need to see your app startup code and possibly a repro on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I see such resolution

```
        // Create DI container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register application modules
        Autofac_RegisterApplicationModules(builder);

        // Register filter provider
        //builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        // Register MVC specific abstractions (HttpRequestBase,HttpResponceBase etc)
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

        // container
        var container = builder.Build();
```

As you can see I commented this row

```
//builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

**BUT I need confirmation if that is ok!**

Please, who knows explain if it is correct and/or how to be.

**TRACE RESULT BELOW - NEED HELP**

```
[InvalidOperationException: The dependency resolver is not of type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver' and does not appear to be wrapped using DynamicProxy from the Castle Project. This issue could be the result of a change in the DynamicProxy implementation or the use of a different proxy library to wrap the dependency resolver.]
   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.get_Current() +367
   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacFilterProvider.GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +196
   System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviderCollection.GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +279
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +436
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +82
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +588
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +484
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +446
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**After my new investigation I found out the issue.**
My website uses MVCSiteMap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xnul.png

I am checking now on how to configure MvcSiteMapProvider to not change DI.

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
```

So I think that I need to change it to true to solve issue.
I am in progress on it now and let you know soon.

Feel free to update my view if you have solution!

Comment: I am hitting this issue as well, but I don't understand the fix. If we stop registering filter providers, won't that cause issues with my code that's depending on those providers?

Comment: I add new answer for this below, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

It is due to MvcSiteMapProvider using it's own DI.

You can resolve the issue by making use of the NuGet package [MvcSiteMapProvider MVC5 Autofac Dependency Injection Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.Autofac/) and setting up Autofac as described in the readme for this project.

Answer (score -1):

i was not working for me this line:

```
 Autofac_RegisterApplicationModules(builder);
```

so i changed it by this:

```
  RegisterAssemblyModules(builder);
```

and it works now.

Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Autofac_RegisterApplicationModules(builder); was just my method where I registered autofac modules and RegisterAssemblyModules(builder); was there. I think that you problem was because you didn't request RegisterAssemblyModules(builder);. So it is not related to my issue.